# Ajuda com PHP e MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, websocket

Olá.

Tenho uma aplicação usando PHP e MongoDB e queria saber se tem alguma maneira de manter a conexão com o mongoDB aberta.

Tenho o seguinte código que conecta ao mongo:

```
private static function findNome($nome) : String {
    $cliente = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://192.168.15.100:27017");
    $db = $cliente->dbName;
}
```

Toda vez que chamo a função `findNome()` abre uma nova conexão com o mongo. Será que tem como deixar essa conexão aberta? precisando chama-lá só uma vez?

Obs: Essa função e chamada via ajax usando jQuery

Answer (score 4):

Pode criar uma variável na classe e fazer assim e criar um método para checar se já esta conectado:

```
private static $mongo;

private static checkConnection()
{
     if (!self::$mongo) {//Verifica se já esta conectado
         self::$mongo = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://192.168.15.100:27017");
     }
}

private static function findNome($nome) : String {
    $db = self::$mongo->dbName;
}
```

---

### Persistência com a lib MongoDB para PHP

Procurei no https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/, mas não encontrei nada sobre persistência, é provável que somente um servidor com suporte para criar Sockets e com isto usar WebSocket você conseguirá manter a conexão. Mas é algo bem complexo e teria que refazer muita coisa, desde o teu back-end até o teu front-end, se eu encontrar algo irei editar a resposta.

Comment: Esse método funciona via ajax? Editei minha pergunta colocando a observação

Comment: @usuario Ajax é no front-end, isso não é relacionado ao Ajax, php roda no back-end ;)

Comment: Teria como deixar a conexão aberta no php? para quando chamar via ajax não tenha que conectar de novo ao mongo? pensei em usar websocket mas não sei como.

Comment: @usuario com Ajax não, procurei no https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/, mas não encontrei nada sobre persistência, é provável que somente um servidor com suporte para criar Sockets e com isto usar WebSocket você conseguirá manter a conexão. Mas é algo bem complexo e teria que refazer muita coisa, desde o teu back-end até o teu front-end.